# Safari crashes when using jQuery datepicker with Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, safari, google-apps-script, datepicker

I'm trying to use the jQuery datepicker on a Google Apps Script with HTML Service.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('Page');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
                   .setTitle('Test Me');

  return htmlOutput;
}
```

Page.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
<div>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div>
```

Hosted Script

> https://script.google.com/d/1CWo9EonsNtS7Q4nYrhIWmtniMqnsUmWcxyusheGV5EO1EwEwNmPXCvzx/edit

Webapp

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzCSzU6ErMtizMWvI5hBI1TIX0Fhj86_OTyvD16rdDM4jCk1obn/exec

Everything works well on Firefox and Chrome. But when I click on the input field on Safari, the browser crashes. Any insight?

Comment: Did you ever gain any insight into why this crash was occurring?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? I tested the webapp on my Safari browser and it seemed to behave as required.

Comment: Just checked on my iPhone and seems to be that whatever the issue had been fixed.